# How to integrate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{\| x -a_1 \|^2+\| x -a_2 \|^2+\| x -a_3 \|^2}{2}} dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to find the following integral

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{\| x -a_1 \|^2+\| x -a_2 \|^2+\| x -a_3 \|^2}{2}} dx
\end{align}

I am having a difficult time combining terms.

Comment: It's sort of obvious that what's in the exponent is a linear combo of $\|x\|^2$, of $\langle x,(a_1+a_2+a_3)/3\rangle$ and of $\sum_i \|a_i\|^2$, so all you have to do is identify 3 coefficients.  Then completing the square is easy.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: I claim there should exist constants $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \|x-a_1\|^2+\|x-a_2\|^2+\|x-a_3\|^2 = 3\|x-a\|^2+c. $$
Find these constants. It would then follow that
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}{e^{-\frac{\|x-a_1\|^2+\|x-a_2\|^2+\|x-a_3\|^2}{2}}\,dx} = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}{e^{-\frac{3\|x-a\|^2+c}{2}}\,dx} = e^{-\frac{c}{2}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}{e^{-\frac{3}{2}\|x-a\|^2}\,dx} = e^{-\frac{c}{2}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}{e^{-\frac{3}{2}\|x\|^2}\,dx}. $$
It would then suffice to calculate that last integral.